# Base arithmetic Reverse

Tags: java

```
public class BaseArithmetic {

    int value2;
    int base2;
    int remainder;
    public void setValues2(int value2, int base2) {
        this.value2 = value2;
        this.base2 = base2;
    }

    public int tenToBase(int n) {
        while (value2 >= base2) {
            remainder = value2%base2;
            value2 = value2/base2;
            System.out.print(remainder);
        }
        return value2;
    }
}
```

Tester:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class BaseArithmeticTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BaseArithmetic Base = new BaseArithmetic();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter the value on 10th base: ");
        int value2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter which base do you want to convert: ");
        int base2 = in.nextInt();
        Base.setValues2(value2, base2);
        System.out.println(Base.tenToBase(value2));
    }
}
```

I wrote this code to convert a value from 10th base to arbitrary base, however for example when I say 19 for value and 2 for base, 11001 is the output but it must be 10011 so how can I reverse these kind of thing? Is there a way to convert System.out outputs to string so I can use for loop to reverse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe contents of System.out is placed in an internal buffer, which emits to the console so it would be impossible to reverse this in runtime.

I believe the best way to do this would to simply append values to a String

```
public int tenToBase(int n) {
    String temp = ""
    while (value2 >= base2) {
        remainder = value2%base2;
        value2 = value2/base2;
        temp = remainder + temp;
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
    return value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to set base. Already util contains radix which can help you.

If you need to convert your input in 6 base, Just do it

```
 int value2 = in.nextInt(6);
```

you can get all info about radix from [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt) Class

### public int nextInt(int radix)

Parameters:

radix - the radix used to interpret the token as an int value